# ffmpeg - how to remove white frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, detect, flashlight

We doing videorecording with strobelight and the framerate is 30 fps.
If we set the strobe below 30hz we got a black frame in the video. if we set the strobe over 30hz we got a white frame.

I found how to remove the blackframe and duping the the frame before using:

```ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i test.avi -vf blackframe=1,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=0:function=less -vsync cfr -c:a copy out.avi
```

But i cant find anything to remove the white frame. Is there any filter i can use?

Greetings 
Frank

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you can negate the frame, then run your blackframe filtering, then negate it back.

`-vf negate,blackframe=..,metadata=..,negate`

Comment: Hey Gyan,that worked perfectly. Only thing i had to do was changing the blackvalue. Thanks :)